# Use PHP to populate Bootstrap dropdown from database

Tags: php, database, dropdown

I know there are a ton of answered questions on this but I must be missing something because nothing is working and I'm losing my mind. Admittedly I don't know what I'm doing but usually can figure it out. Not this time.

I have an html page using bootstrap, and a form on the page that is working fine. Users enter text into the form fields, and PHP takes the form fields, inserts them into a document, and produces a DOC that the user downloads.

I'm trying to put a dropdown menu in the form, and populate the options in the dropdown from a database table on my bluehost server. I've tried hacking my way through 20 different variations, and either the dropdown doesn't populate (example below) or a chunk of code from the query appears surrounding the dropdown on the rendered page.

This is placed above my `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page:

```
<?php


$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$databaseName = "mydatabase";



$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytablename`";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

?>
```

And here is the code in the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control">

            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
            <option><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>

  </select>
</div>
```

My database table is titled: `mytablename`

The database has 2 columns - 1) `id` 2) `name`

This version doesn't show any errors (unlike some other attempts I've made where parts of the search query render on the page, instead of being executed) and shows a dropdown menu but it's blank without any options.

Can anyone guess where I'm going wrong?

Comment: try print_r($result1) after mysqli_query function and tell what you get

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I answered the question below. Apparently I didn't have enough permissions set on the user I was using to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, this is embarrassing, but it looks like the user I was using to connect to the database did not have sufficient permissions. I thought when I created the user I set it up as having all privileges, but apparently not. There goes a whole day of work.

Thank you to all who looked at this.

Comment: I voted to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced

Comment: I want to but it makes you wait 48 hrs to answer your own question. Unless theres another way to get rid if it.